# Using perf probe to monitor performance stats during a particular function

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, perf

I'm trying to monitor performance stats during a particular function using linux perf tool.

I was following the instructions given at https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Jolsa_Features_Togle_Event#Example_-_using_u.28ret.29probes

I tried to get instruction count of a simple C program. (As shown below)

1) My simple C code

```
#include<stdio.h>

int sum=0;
int i=0;

void func(void)
{
   for(i=0;i<100;i++)
   {
     sum=sum+i;
   }
}

int main(void)
{
   func();
   return 0;
}
```

2) Compiling and adding probes

```
root@sunimal-laptop:/home/sunimal/temp# gcc -o ex source.c 
root@sunimal-laptop:/home/sunimal/temp# perf probe -x ./ex entry=func
Added new event:
  probe_ex:entry       (on 0x4ed)

You can now use it in all perf tools, such as:

        perf record -e probe_ex:entry -aR sleep 1

root@sunimal-laptop:/home/sunimal/temp# perf probe -x ./ex exit=func%return
Added new event:
  probe_ex:exit        (on 0x4ed%return)

You can now use it in all perf tools, such as:

        perf record -e probe_ex:exit -aR sleep 1
```

3) Trying to use perf stat to measure the instruction count within the func() function. This leads to an error.

```
root@sunimal-laptop:/home/sunimal/temp# perf stat -e instructions:u,probe_ex:entry/on=instructions/,probe_ex:exit/off=instructions/ ./ex
invalid or unsupported event: 'instructions:u,probe_ex:entry/on=instructions/,probe_ex:exit/off=instructions/'
Run 'perf list' for a list of valid events
```

Could someone point me where I did wrong?

[I'm using linux kernel 3.11.0-12-generic]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the instructions you are following are not yet included into the mainline Linux kernel. As a consequence, perf is telling you that the events are not supported: perf doesn't know the "toggle" mechanism mentioned on this page.

I can see two workarounds:

1. If you have access to the source code you want to profile you can use the [perf_event_open](http://linux.die.net/man/2/perf_event_open) system call directly from your source code to start and stop counting on function entry and exit.
2. Clone jolsa repository `git clone https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/jolsa/perf` switch the core_toggle branch `git co remotes/origin/perf/core_toggle` and then compile and run the kernel with this support.

Regarding 2, I am not familiar at all with kernel versions and development and I think that this solution may be quie complex to use and maintain. Maybe you should ask on the [perf users mailing list](http://dir.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel.perf.user) if there are any plans for the toggle feature to be integrated into the mainline kernel.

Comment: Manuel, there is toggle in the default perf_event_open: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/perf_event_open.2.html "perf_event ioctl calls" -  PERF_EVENT_IOC_ENABLE/PERF_EVENT_IOC_DISABLE; but they can be used only with fd from perf_event_open...