# How to use perf with ld_preload?

Tags: environment-variables, perf, ld-preload

I tried to use `perf stat` with `LD_PRELOAD` as prefix for executable such as:

```
perf stat LD_PRELOAD=$PWD/../user/preload.so ./write 1
```

It seems not work for perf, are there any way to achieve it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
perf stat env LD_PRELOAD=....  ./write 1
```

That should work, although that means `/usr/bin/env` is the process being profiled so you're getting its overhead, too.  At least it's cheaper than a command like `sh -c 'LD_PRELOAD=... exec ./write 1'`.

If startup overhead becomes a problem, you can have your `write` itself fork/exec `perf stat -p <PID>` on itself.  [perf stat for part of program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26267588/perf-stat-for-part-of-program)